# Lookup Field to show particular records

Tags: apex, lookup, lookup-filter, dependent-lookup

I want to create a lookup field in which if user's Country is US then he can only see records of country US when he clicks on lookup and If user's country is UK then he can see records of  UK

Comment: If this is for the convenience of the user lookup filters could work, but complexity around u.s vs united states, etc.  if you are trying to restrict record visibility, you need to use Sharing rules as indicated in Sergey answer

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be use of "[Criteria-Based Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en)".

Assuming you have some country field in the object, you could set the rules so some user or group of users can see only country based records.